# Atheros AR9271 not recognized on Ubuntu16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, usb, atheros

I just got my first wifi chipset : USB wireless card Atheros AR9271 but when plugging it to my device it doesn't seem to be recognized.

After reading [this link in French from doc.ubuntu-fr.org](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/wifi_liste_carte) it doesn't seem that it is compatible with 16.04 Ubuntu version. Before being condemned to buy another one I would have loved to hear your opinion about it.

Here's the output of lsusb with the wireless card plugged in :

```
antoine@antoine-Inspiron-3543:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5756 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 13d3:3327 IMC Networks 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It seems to be the line about IMC Networks as a far as it is the only one that vary.

I unplugged the device, as root, ran journalctl -fa and plugged the device in. The following showed up in the log:

```
antoine@antoine-Inspiron-3543:~$ journalctl -fa
-- Logs begin at lun. 2017-09-11 18:02:34 CEST. --
sept. 11 17:02:52 antoine-Inspiron-3543 NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  [1505142172.8596] (wlx485d605766e9): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
sept. 11 17:02:52 antoine-Inspiron-3543 wpa_supplicant[1528]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
sept. 11 17:02:52 antoine-Inspiron-3543 wpa_supplicant[1528]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
sept. 11 17:02:52 antoine-Inspiron-3543 NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  [1505142172.9292] device (wlx485d605766e9): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
sept. 11 17:02:52 antoine-Inspiron-3543 NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  [1505142172.9295] device (wlx485d605766e9): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
sept. 11 17:02:52 antoine-Inspiron-3543 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx485d605766e9: link is not ready
sept. 11 17:02:54 antoine-Inspiron-3543 wpa_supplicant[1528]: wlx485d605766e9: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
sept. 11 17:02:54 antoine-Inspiron-3543 NetworkManager[1070]: <info>  [1505142174.5815] device (wlx485d605766e9): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
sept. 11 17:02:54 antoine-Inspiron-3543 ModemManager[994]: <info>  Couldn't find support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2': not supported by any plugin
sept. 11 17:02:56 antoine-Inspiron-3543 wpa_supplicant[1528]: wlx485d605766e9: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=BEACON_HINT type=UNKNOWN
```

Some of these lines were red.

The output of sudo lshw -class network:

```
antoine@antoine-Inspiron-3543:~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 01
       serial: ac:d1:b8:d2:ee:b3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.0.42 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7100000-f7107fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: 20:47:47:16:a9:99
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:48 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7000000-f7000fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1.2
       logical name: wlx485d605766e9
       serial: 48:5d:60:57:66:e9
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k_htc driverversion=4.10.0-33-generic firmware=1.4 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

The output of lspci:

```
antoine@antoine-Inspiron-3543:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

The output of rfkill list all:

antoine@antoine-Inspiron-3543:~$ rfkill list all

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
8: phy6: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Any help would be appreciate.